# Creating a memory leak in PhP

Tags: php

Today I was asked to create a memory leak (on purpose) in PhP. Now, I am more experienced in #c & c++.

I know that there is no garbage collector in #c, so memory leak in c+ is usually created by losing a reference from a variable before using malloc to remove it from the stack.

In java and PhP I understand memory is leaked when you forget to remove references.

So one of the simplest ways anyone could create a leak would be:

```
$leak = [];
$ticks = 0;
while(true){
    $leak[$ticks] = getHugeObject();
    $ticks++;
    unset($leaks[$ticks]); //This creates a memory leak because the tick was already added, before that object gets removed.
}
//Program should crash after reaching memory limit.
```

This is pretty easy. However, I am not allowed to use arrays to create the leak. So I feel incredibility dumb for not being able to complete such a simple task. Ideas?

Comment: you can create/reference variables by scalar values and simple expressions in php using curly braces or "variable variables". `${"varname".$ticks}` would create a variable named `$varname0` then `$varname1`...etc. "variable variables" works similar, using two dollar signs: `$var = 'foo'; $$var = 'bar';` would create a variable `$foo` with the value `$bar`.

Comment: Generally PHP runs sandboxed so all resources it takes are cleaned up when its finished running a script. You can still have leaky code while a long script is running though just by keeping active references to things. For a larger problem there's shared resources (like persistent connections) which are not deallocated and can indeed cause longer living problems.

Comment: I don't understand `unset($leaks[$ticks]);`. You are attempting to unset a variable which does not get set until the next iteration. All that it's causing is an increase in time because the code would run faster without it and produce the same exact result.

Comment: I don't know if PHP has any true memory leaks. Memory exhaustion is easily achieved with poorly written code but a leak would generally be caused by a native PHP function whose underlying C code has a leak.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That was intended to create the memory leak in the example.

Comment: Based on your example then `$var = 'a'; while(true){$var .= $var;}` is a memory leak.

Comment: How though? You are just re-assigning a value to $var when you do $var .= $var;

Comment: Because it satisfies `//Program should crash after reaching memory limit.`. I personally love using http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ for testing random junk so feel free to try it there.

Comment: Also, what in the heck is the `c+` programming language? Are you talking about `c++` or `c#` (c-sharp)? Please provide a link for this mystical `c+` language; I would like to learn it.